# Using gsub only when the string is included in the text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The app that I'm building allows users to store first and last names of contacts. First names are mandatory, but, last names aren't. In some cases they exist and in some cases they don't.

I tried using the following logic to replace FNAME and LNAME in the mailer. I had to use this in the mailer because the logic for sending the group mail gives me no room elsewhere.

```
message = @mailer.message.gsub! 'FNAME', contact.first_name if @mailer.message includes? ('FNAME')
@body = message.gsub! 'LNAME', contact.last_name || '' if message includes?('LNAME')
```

This throws an `undefined method`includes?'`with`error class NoMethodError`. Ideally I would like to ignore gsub! if there is no LNAME or FNAME in the message.

Comment: When your question involves an exception that has been raised, please provide the actual error message (without the backtrace, if that's not relevant) and tell us where it occurred (which line of your code). Here, for example, it should tell you which object does not have a method `includes?`. That is a vital piece of information. More generally, when the reason for an error message is not obvious, you need to study the message carefully for clues to the source of the problem.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the feedback. I'll definitely be more descriptive in the future.

Comment: When you move beyond a single method and start adding trailing conditional tests, it's a good idea to use parenthesis to delimit the parameters to the called method. That helps others read your code, and also helps the interpreter understand what are parameters to the method and what follow them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a missing dot before the `#includes?` method call:

```
message = @mailer.message.gsub! 'FNAME', contact.first_name if @mailer.message.includes?('FNAME')
```

But you don't need to check the existence of the substring with `#includes?` `#gsub!` will only replace the content if there is a match, so:

```
message = @mailer.message.gsub!('FNAME', contact.first_name)
```

Is enough, if `@mailer.message` could be `nil`, then a further check is needed:

```
message = @mailer.message.gsub!('FNAME', contact.first_name) if @mailer.message.present?
```

And BTW `#gsub!` will modify the original string, so you probably what you really wanted to write is:

```
if @mailer.message.present?
  @mailer.message.gsub!('FNAME', contact.first_name)
  @mailer.message.gsub!('LNAME', contact.last_name)
end
```

Comment: You can also use try for this sort of thing, as in
`@mailer.message.try(:gsub!, 'FNAME', contact.first_name)`, in which case you wouldn't need to check message.present?